# In what line is my inline-block and how high is this line

Tags: javascript

I have a block with a few inline-blocks inside. These all have varying heights and widths. I have line wrap enabled.

[image: reference image of what's described above]

What I'm trying to do is if I have a reference to one of the inline-blocks to

1. find out what line it is in and
2. how high that line is. (I can't change the HTML)

**2** has the obvious solution of getting the bounding boxes of all blocks in the line and using the highest height as the height of the line. Here I'm just wondering if there is a more performant solution for that.

My main interest lies in a). My idea of an incredibly imperformant solution would be doing b) for all lines in the parent block and then comparing the offset-top of the searched element to the line-heights. I was hoping maybe someone can come up with a better idea?

edit:
relevant part of the html, css and js i'm using:

```html
<div>
 <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

```css
div {
 display: block;
 background-color: yellow;
 height: 600px;
 width: 2000px;
}

div > div {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px;
}
```

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 const nodes = document.querySelectorAll("div > div");
 for(let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  nodes[i].style.width = `${5 + Math.random() * 200}px`;
  nodes[i].style.height = `${5 + Math.random() * 200}px`;
  nodes[i].style.backgroundColor = `hsl(${(Math.random() * 360)}, 100%, 50%)`;
 }

 const nodeiwanttogetdescribeddataof = nodes[4];

 //code to get the data
});
```

i did not implement the ideas described as i was hoping to not need to. the purpose of the question was to find out whether there is some easy way to do what i need, for example (pseudocode) `let theline = node.line`.

Comment: You should post your html, your css, and your incredibly imperformant  solution.

Comment: If you have some code that you wrote yourself and you want a review of the performance and all other aspects of that code, you might be better served by reading the help center of [codereview.se] and seeing if this question is on topic there. As it is, with no code and nothing to compare against, this question does not seem to meet the guidelines spelled out in [ask].